# Socket.io + express rooms

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am working on an online website with real-time chat and I've been trying to set up socket.io rooms for a few days now, but one of my custom events just doesn't emit.

My website has 2 paths, `/` and `/play`. When someone fills out a form in the `/` path, the website redirects them to the `/play` path.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(listener);

io.on('connection', socket => {

  socket.on('add user', data => { // This event gets emitted when the user submits the form at `/`, in a client-side js file. 
    socket.username = data.username;
    socket.room = data.room;
    socket.score = 0;
    socket.join(data.room);
    io.sockets.in(data.room).emit('user joined', { // This event gets 'handled', in another (not the same one) client-size js file.
    username: data.username,
    room: data.room
  });
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
   io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('user left', {
   username: socket.username,
   room: socket.room
  });
  socket.leave(socket.room)
});


});
```

In the other client-side js file:

```
var socket = io.connect();  
let joined = 0;

socket.on('user joined', data => {
  joined++;
  console.log(joined, data)
  const elemental = document.createElement("LI");
  const info = document.createTextNode(data.username);
     elemental.appendChild(info);
   document.getElementById('people').appendChild(info)
});
```

The add user event code executes just fine, but the user joined one doesn't..
I'm almost certain that it has to do with the paths. I read on socket.io namespaces but it seems like they are just like a different type of rooms.
Can someone tell me what's wrong?

EDIT: I should mention that no errors come up.

Comment: have you tried: `socket.on('error', console.log);` on  `client-side.js`?

Comment: Just tried it - nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your whole code, I'm going to assume that the socket on `client-side.js` code, is not joined to the `data.room` room, and that's why you don't get anything on the `'user join'` event listener and that happens because you probably have multiple `socket.io` connections on the client side code.

You have multiple ways to solve this, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

- Instead of only emitting to people on the room, emit to all sockets that an user joined a specific room. `io.emit('user joined')` instead of `io.sockets.in(data.room)...`
- There should only be one single `var socket = io.connect();` on the front end, otherwise the socket that's emitting: `add user` and therefore joined to `data.room` is not the same socket that's listening on: `user joined`, and that's why you never get the event on that socket, because you have 2 different sockets, one that joined the room, and one that is doing absolutely nothing except waiting for an event that will never occur.